# Query to compare between date with time and date without time - python using access db

Tags: python, ms-access

I need help to create query to compare between date with time and date without time. I am using python with access db (pypyodbc).

In the database I have a column that contains date/time (includes time), and in python I have a datetime object (without time).

I want to write a sql query that compares just the dates of the two.

For Example:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MDSSDB WHERE [ValidStartTime] = #2016-05-17#")
```

The ValidStartTime includes time so it doesn't work. I want just the date from the ValidStartTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using MS Access' [`DateValue`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateValue-Function-03878f08-b0db-42df-8a0c-279939637c6f) function that extracts only the date component (`TimeValue` being the time component counterpart).

Also, consider passing your date value as parameter to better integrate with your Python environment with no need to concatenate into Access' `#` form. Below passes a parameter as tuple of one item:

```
from datetime import datetime

...
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MDSSDB WHERE DateValue([ValidStartTime]) = ?", (datetime(2016, 5, 17),))
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that `WHERE DateValue([ValidStartTime])` is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) so the query will always do a table scan, even if there is an index on `ValidStartTime`.